# Sprite Smooth movement and facing position according to movement

Tags: processing.js

i'm trying to make this interaction with keyboard for movement using some sprites and i got stuck with two situations. 
 1) The character movement is not going acording to the animation itself (it only begin moving after one second or so while it's already being animated). What i really want it to do is, to move without a "initial acceleration feeling" that i get because of this problem 
 2) I can't think of a way to make the character face the position it should be facing when the key is released. I'll post the code here, but since it need images to work correctly and is not so small i made a skecth available at this link if you want to check it out: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/439572

```java
PImage[] reverseRun = new PImage [16];

PImage[] zeroArray = new PImage [16];

void setup(){
  size(800,600);
  //Right Facing
  for(int i = 0; i < zeroArray.length; i++){
    zeroArray[i] = loadImage (i + ".png");
    zeroArray[i].resize(155,155);
    }
  //Left Facing
  for( int z = 0; z < reverseRun.length; z++){
    reverseRun[z] = loadImage ( "mirror" + z + ".png");
    reverseRun[z].resize(155,155);
    }
  }

void draw(){
  frameRate(15);
  background(255);
  imageMode(CENTER);

  if(x > width+10){
    x = 0;
  } else if (x < - 10){
    x = width;}






if (i >= zeroArray.length){
  i  = 3;} //looping to generate constant motiion 

if ( z >= reverseRun.length){
    z = 3;} //looping to generate constant motiion 

if (isRight) {
     image(zeroArray[i], x, 300);
     i++;
  } //going through the images at the array
else if (isLeft) {
     image(reverseRun[z],x,300);
     z++;
  } going through the images at the array

else if(!isRight){
     image(zeroArray[i], x, 300);
     i = 0; } //"stoped" sprite
  }
}




 //movement
float x = 300;
float y  = 300;
float i = 0;
float z = 0;
float speed = 25;
boolean isLeft, isRight, isUp, isDown; 
void keyPressed() {




setMove(keyCode, true);

 if (isLeft ){
   x -= speed;
 }
 if(isRight){
   x += speed;
 }
}

void keyReleased() {
  setMove(keyCode, false);

}

boolean setMove(int k, boolean b) {
  switch (k) {
  case UP:
    return isUp = b;

  case DOWN:
    return isDown = b;

  case LEFT:
    return isLeft = b;

  case RIGHT:
    return isRight = b;

  default:
    return b;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The movement problem is caused by your operating system setting a delay between key presses. Try this out by going to a text editor and holding down a key. You'll notice that a character shows up immediately, followed by a delay, followed by the character repeating until you release the key.

That delay is also happening between calls to the `keyPressed()` function. And since you're moving the character (by modifying the `x` variable) inside the `keyPressed()` function, you're seeing a delay in the movement.

The solution to this problem is to check which key is pressed instead of relying solely on the `keyPressed()` function. You could use the `keyCode` variable inside the `draw()` function, or you could keep track of which key is pressed using a set of `boolean` variables.

Note that you're actually already doing that with the `isLeft` and `isRight` variables. But you're only checking them in the `keyPressed()` function, which defeats the purpose of them because of the problem I outlined above.

In other words, move this block from the `keyPressed()` function so it's inside the `draw()` function instead:

```
if (isLeft ){
  x -= speed;
}
if(isRight){
  x += speed;
}
```

As for knowing which way to face when the character is not moving, you could do that using another `boolean` value that keeps track of which direction you're facing.

Side note: you should really try to properly indent your code, as right now it's pretty hard to read.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on user input in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input).

Comment: Thanks once again kevin workman you saved my day. Btw your site is awesome i'm going to use it to study more.